# Mocking a RestTemplate and return object based in json file in Spring v1.5.14.RELEASE

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have this RestTemplate that I want to mock and return an object based on a json file

```
    ResponseEntity<List<Hotel>> deliveryResponse =
                        restTemplate.exchange(link.getHref(),
                                HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Hotel>>() {
                                });
```

the mock I try:

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(eq("delivery"), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(), eq(Object.class)))
                .thenReturn(readObjectFromFile("hotel.json", Order.class));
```

and

```
private <T> T readObjectFromFile(final String fileName, final Class<T> clazz) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("__files/" + fileName), clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

but I have this compilation error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(T)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a typo?
Try this.

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(eq("delivery"), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(), eq(Object.class)))
                .thenReturn(readObjectFromFile("hotel.json"), Order.class);
```